# wordpress responsive got corrupted

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this site I am trying to build in wordpress.
http://denverkollel.org/site/about-us/

for some reason on a cellphone or emulator, the page is too wide for the screen and gets cut off.
but if you go back to the original theme, it works just fine.

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_46791/about-us/

can anyone help figure out what it might be that got touched while i was working on the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a margin left on your span class that's causing this.

```
[class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 22px !important;
}
```

remove that and it will lok nice